# mysql Query to get next results

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get next few results in mysql with some condition?

```
+-----+---------------+-------------------------+
| id  | update_type   |    message              |
+-----+-----------------------------------------+
| 1   |   10          | One tow three           |
| 2   |   20          | No error in this        |
| 3   |   0           | My testing message      |
| 4   |   0           | php module test         |
| 5   |   30          | hello world             |
| 6   |   0           | team spirit             |
| 7   |   40          | puzzle game             |
| 8   |   50          | social game             |
| 9   |   0           | stackoverflow           |
|10   |   0           | stackexchange           |
+-----+---------------+-------------------------+
```

In the above table how can I get all messages from `update_type=20` and till update_type changes to `30`. (Above table is static and value of `0` and can expand upto many next rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries for this purpose.  Assuming each value occurs once:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id >= (select t2.id from t t2 where t2.update_type = 20) and
      t.id <= (select t2.id from t t2 where t2.update_type = 30);
```

If the values appear more than once, then this query will generate an error (the subquery is expected to return only one value).  What you want to do in this case is not clear, but `min()` or `max()` in the subqueries can help.

Answer (score 0):

If I did get your question rigt, you are looking for a solution in SQL. If that's the point, then you can make a condition in the where-clause. i.e.

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnname BETWEEN 20 AND 30;`

You have to replace `tablename` with the name of your table. and `columnname` with your corresponding column in the table. Then you can enter the `WHERE` in the statement. In your case the condition is `BETWEEN`.